# Using 'if', '&&', and '||' in one condition statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So what I am trying to accomplish is if @provider.licenses.where(issuing_state:'CA')' it has to match the @form.state as well which would be 'CA' in this case in order to have access to that page. Now if the provider.licenses.issuing_state does not match @form.state the user would be redirect. Here is what I have

```
def edit
        @user = current_user
        @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
        @form_response = FormResponse.find_by_id(params[:id])
        @form = @form_response.form
        @provider = current_user.try(:provider)
        @provider_user = @provider.try(:role).try(:user)

        if current_user.is_provider?
            if @provider.licenses.where(issuing_state:'CO') && @form.state == 'CA' || @provider.licenses.where(issuing_state:'CA') && @form.state == 'CO' 
                redirect_to root_path, alert: 'You do not have access to update form'

            end 
        end
    end
```

Comment: Try putting parentheses around each set of conditions joined by &&. Like `(a && b) || (c && d)`.

Comment: I tried that and it redirect the user every time no matter if the state of the provider and form matches

Comment: `@provider.licenses.where(issuing_state:'CO')` is always truthy because it is an ActiveRecord relation object. Do you mean to check for the existence of such a record?

Comment: ahh you are right. And yes i do mean to check for an existence of such a record @muistooshort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `@provider.licenses.where(..)` is always trueish because it returns a `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

You might want to use `@provider.licenses.exist?(issuing_state:'CO')` instead.

```
if @provider.licenses.exist?(issuing_state:'CO') && @form.state == 'CA' ||
   @provider.licenses.exist?(issuing_state:'CA') && @form.state == 'CO'
  redirect_to root_path, alert: 'You do not have access to update form'
end
```

Comment: wow that's all that I was missing. Thank you so much. I was just over thinking it.

Comment: and just curios does .exist? check for nil ?